# Why does the Terminal tab keep popping up on my MacBook Pro when I try to shut it down?

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, plugins

Recently, I started having problems with my MacBook Pro. Everytime I try to shut it down, the Terminal tab opens and shows the message on the picture (root#/usr/local/VASCO/NativeBridge/startup.sh ; exit;)

I do not understand at all where the problem lies. I have tried to delete the VASCO plug-in, but it doesn't work.

Do you have an idea of what the problem might be?

Many thanks!

J.

[image]

Comment: Are you using Terminal or iTerm2?

Comment: Terminal is the tab that pops up everytime I try to shut down. There is no way to shut it down as the Terminal tab does not want to close. It says that all sh, digipass-nativebridge-monitor, digipass-nativebridge process will stop if I shut down the computer. I have no idea what this means.

Comment: When I try to shut the Mac down, I am asked if I really want to stop the running process underway in this tab. But I did not even open Terminal myself in the first place. I hence cannot see what process they are talking about...

Comment: `/usr/local/VASCO/NativeBridge/startup.sh` is not a default part of **macOS** and if you didn't install it and this is a personal computer then you need to ascertain its origin and purpose and deal with it in an appropriate manner. BTW I would not change any of the profile settings in **Terminal** as suggested in the answer by jmh because all that would do is hide the underlying issue not really resolve it in a proper investigative manner as really should be done!

Comment: Thank you for your input. Unfortunately, I am not very good with computers. The only thing I know is that VASCO is the plugin used to read banking cards on my computer. So I might have installed the plugin to allow for the use of my card. Should I delete the plugin/ card reader altogether? This is the first time this has happened though and I didn't install the plugin recently. This was months ago.

Answer (score -1):

Open terminal and under the Terminal menu item click on preferences. This will give you the pane shown below.

[image]

From this pane click on Profiles in the upper left corner of the pane and notice below the Profiles pane but to the right there is a set of tabs.  Click on the Shell tab.  This opens a pane shown below.

[image]

Notice that around the middle of this pane is the phrase: Ask before closing. I've drawn a red rectangle around this. Now make sure the Never button is checked.

Comment: Why the down vote??